# django rest framework - password hashing

Tags: authentication, hash, django-rest-framework, basic-authentication, password-hash

It drives me crazy... I read tons of posts about how to hash your password when creating a user, but for some reason is just won't work and I can't authenticate.

I am using **django 1.8.1** and **django-rest-framework 3.1.2**

**My code:**

**views.py:**

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
               mixins.ListModelMixin,
               viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

**----EDIT----**

With this code, the password appears as is in the database and is not hashed, so I can't authenticate.

**serializers.py:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password' )
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            username=validated_data['username'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

**And also - what method does `serializer.save()` call??**

Any idea??? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Serializers don't have a `post_save` method, not even before v3. You must be confused with the `post_save` in generic views. The generic view's `pre_save` and `post_save` hooks no longer exist, but are replaced with `perform_create` and `perform_update`.

You just need to do `obj.set_password` in user serializer's `create` method. There's an [example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) in the docs that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it.  And do I leave the create method in the UserViewSet as is?  And also,  what method exactly does serializer.save() call?

Comment: You can actually remove the create method in your viewset. serializer.save() knows when to call the serializer's update method or create method.

Comment: But doesn't the url being translated into a view?  I mean,  without the create method in the ViewSet how will it know to call the serializer.save()?  Just trying to understand the  whole thing..

Comment: You're using the [CreateModelMixin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin) which implements creating and saving a new model instance.

Comment: I tried the piece of code from the docs - it is not hashing the password, it appears as is in the database. I think I don't even get to the serializer code (when I put breakpoints in the create method, it doesn't get there). also checked and with or without the create method in the serializer makes no difference in the database, so the create code doesn't execute. ideas?